# OpenLayer2 Tween animation callback not working when the browser tab is inactive

Tags: pyqgis, openlayers-2, javascript

I have data dumping in my db after some interval from resources.The geometry from the data then calling by JS interval function after every ten seconds.using this function to animate my feature http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Tween-js.html. i which the size of the point change via callback function and represents like animation. All things are working fine when I am on the browser tab. But when i am not on my application tab and during that period if some features draw on my WMS layer then they did not animate normally but stuck like into there begin size. i have tried to console something in mention callback variable. but the behavior i have faced is that all my callbacks kind of stuck or in the waiting mode. When i come back to my browser tab or activate my tab that waiting consoles executes then immediately.

```
// tween animation
function animatLayer(layer) {
    var animationTween = new OpenLayers.Tween(OpenLayers.Easing.Quad.easeInOut);
    var begin = {
        x: 20
    }
    var end = {
        x: 2
    }
    var callbacks = {
        eachStep: OpenLayers.Function.bind(animate, layer),
        done: function () {
            animationTween = new OpenLayers.Tween(OpenLayers.Easing.Quad.easeInOut);
            begin.x = (begin.x == 20 ? 5 : 20);
            end.x = (end.x == 20 ? 5 : 20);
            console.log('callback')
        }
    }
    animationTween.start(begin, end, 80, {
        callbacks: callbacks
    });
}

function animate(delta) {
    for (var i = this.len; i < this.features.length; i++) {
      this.features[i].style.strokeWidth = delta.x;
      this.features[i].style.pointRadius = delta.x;
    }
    this.redraw();
  }
```

The call is not happening when the browser tab is inactive so in that case the point got stuck into its max position and does not animate.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour].  What is your actual question?  How to make it animate while inactive?  How to bypass the animation if the tab is inactive?  How to make the browser tab active?  Or something else?

Comment: @Midavalo i have edited the question with more explanation. kindly take a look. really appreciate your help. Thanks